# AJAX response error: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, firebase

**CODE:**

FRONT-END

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.delete-post').on('click', function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var section = $(this).data('section');
            var url = '/users/delete/'+id;
            if(confirm("Delete Post ?")){
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type:'DELETE',
                    success: function(result){
                        console.log('Deleting post...');
                        window.location.href='/users/profile';
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

BACK-END:

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', function(req, res, next) {

    var id = req.params.id;
    var section = req.params.section;

    var image = "";
    var author = "";

    var postRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/"+section+"/"+id);
    var userRef = firebase.database().ref("users/posts/"+id);
    var likesRef = firebase.database().ref("users/likes/"+id);
    var hotRef = firebase.database().ref("hot/"+section+"/"+id);

    postRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
        image = snapshot.image;
        author = snapshot.author;

        if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid.toString() == author) {
            var file = bucket.file(image);

            file.delete(function (err, apiResponse) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  }
                  else {
                    console.log("Deleted successfully");

                    postRef.remove();
                    userRef.remove();
                    hotRef.remove();
                    likesRef.remove();

                    req.flash('success_msg','Post Deleted');
                    res.send(200);
                  }
            });
        }    
    });
});
```

---

**SITUATION:**

I added delete buttons so the user could delete his posts.

When the user clicks the button an AJAX request is made to my Node.js server.

But I get the following error:

---

**ERROR:**

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

---

**QUESTION:**

What is this error and how do I fix it ?

Comment: The error is unrelated to the code you have provided.

Comment: @KevinB I updated my question.

Comment: Are you sure that when you fail to call res.send that something else somewhere else is sending a response? currently if there's an error or a callback doesn't get called your request won't end...

Comment: @Kevin Are you saying I need to add a res.send(200) inside my if statement for the error case ?

Comment: maybe not 200, but yeah it wouldn't be a bad idea to always respond in one way or another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response you're getting is actually *correct*. Per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-delete), Firebase returns a 200 status code and *an empty response*. `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` is exactly that. What you should do is check for both `null` and a `200` status code in the response; if true, you can safely assume that the post was deleted.

My personal opinion is that Firebase should really consider returning something more substantial than *nothing* and a generic, catch-all status code. I'd prefer something like 204 No Content, or 410 Gone. But, alas.

—

Side note: this conditional will never return anything if the post doesn't belong to the author — your API should still return *something* (an error, probably in this case) even if your conditional doesn't match. Like:

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid.toString() == author) { 
    // your code
} else {
    res.status(401).send("User does not have permission to complete the operation.")
}
```

Comment: That was it. Let me just try to fix this and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, I debugged it. The issue is that section is null when passed in req.params.section

Comment: Apparently, I passed it wrong inside my JQuery. Do you see how to fix it ?

Comment: Uh, well if you're debugging and section is null, figure out why? Either you're not sending it a value or the form has a bug?

Comment: Well, I thought you would know by checking my Jquery and could therefore make a complete answer that analyses the issue AND solves it :) Nervemind. I'll do that tomorrow. Unless someone provides the solution in the mean time, I will accept your answer. Have a nice day ^^

Comment: Can't really know for sure without seeing the entire flow from the browser to the backend response. Should be easy to debug on your end though.

Comment: After reading and re-reading your question, it looks like your problem isn't related to the firebase response at all - if you're getting the error in the jQuery implementation, is the post deleted out of Firebase as expected? `res.send(200)` returns a 200 response, and "OK", and thus would not cause `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Comment: I told you that "section" was null. I was just asking how to pass section alongside id inside my jQuery :) because I was clearly doing it wrong. The question is basically, how do I pass 2 variables at the same time in my JQuery since I am not doing it right. Btw, I don't know who downvoted you, but that's kind of mean. Let me upvote you to compensate that.

Comment: Ok, I passed section. The issue is actually in my firebase function.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that. One last thing though: I get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED once my first Firebase remove() is executed... and then the other removes are not executed.