# Why does this client side $.get() request only run the server side code successfully?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I have created a contact form that sends a get request to a route I have hosted locally from a node(express) server. I send the get request when an element is clicked on the dom.

```
($(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sendEmail').click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let name = $('#name').val();
    let email = $('#email').val();

    $.get("http://localhost:3000/send", {name: name, email: email})
    .done(() => {
        alert('success!');
    })
    .fail(() => {
        alert('That did not work');
    })
})($)
```

The node server generates an email based off of information that is gathered from the client. The good news is that the email that is generated works perfectly, and is emailed to my gmail account using [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer).

```
app.get('/send', (req, res) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    name: req.query.name,
    email: req.query.email,
    message: req.query.message,
    to: "",
    from: req.query.name,
    text: ""
  }

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      response.end('error');
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent!');
      response.end('sent')
    }
  })
})
```

Everything is successful server side but no client side code runs after that. Neither my $.done() function or my $.fail() function end up running. What do I need to do so that I can run client side code after the email sends (or doesn't send)?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: none presently @Danny

Comment: After a few minutes I got net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE logged to the console. This article talks about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602271/ajax-response-error-neterr-empty-response The email also sent more than once. It is rather strange behavior I am certainly unfamiliar with. @Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't response the result to the client.
You need call 'res' instead of 'response' in the callback of 'sendMail':

```
app.get('/send', (req, res) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    name: req.query.name,
    email: req.query.email,
    message: req.query.message,
    to: "",
    from: req.query.name,
    text: ""
  }

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);

      //response.end('error');
      res.end('error'); // <=====================

    } else {
      console.log('Email sent!');
      //response.end('sent')
      res.end('Email sent!'); // <=====================
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Oh wow! That seems to have worked. I would have never thought of trying that.